# Get array length in PineScript

Tags: pine-script

If I have some array named `arr` in Pine, how do I get its length? The Pine [reference](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference) doesn't have any results for `array.len`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built in array.size() function

```
array.size(arr)
```

[https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_array{dot}size](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_array%7Bdot%7Dsize)